# How do I set the response format to the same format as the request?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a custom dispatcher to handle versioning that uses a customer media type. It looks something like this:

```
application/vnd.mycompany.myapi-v1+json
```

The extraction of the version number in order to select the correct controller is all up and working, but being new to MVC, I am not sure how to set the response format. What we want to do is set the response format to match the request. So in this example, the response will be in json. Now I assume I'm going to have to extract that from this content type as well which is fine, but could someone give me an example of how i set the response format of this request in MVC4 assuming I have already created the method which will extract the format as a string?

```
private string GetResponseFormat(){
   //some shennanigans here
}
```

P.S. the reason for not having the client use the accept header during the request is that there are already clients out there that are using our old service which would set the accept header to match the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `Content` method to return custom response type:

```
string responseType = GetResponseFormat();
...
switch(responseType){
    case "json":
        string json = "yourJSON";
        return Content(json, "application/json");
    case "xml":
        string xml = "yourXML";
        return Content(xml, "text/xml");
    default:
        string plaintxt = "yourPlaintext";
        return Content(plaintxt, "text/plain"):
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear the existing Accept header and add to it:

```
private void SetResponseFormatToRequestFormat(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    // figure out what the request format was
    _contentTypeHeader = request.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
    if(_contentTypeHeader.Contains("xml")) _contentType = "application/xml";
    if (_contentTypeHeader.Contains("json")) _contentType = "application/json";

    // set response format to the same as the request format
    request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_contentType));
}
```